# How to unbottleneck cpu-bound OpenSSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, performance, openssh

```
sneak@nostromo-2:~$ for i in 3des-cbc aes128-cbc aes128-ctr aes128-gcm@openssh.com aes192-cbc aes192-ctr aes256-cbc aes256-ctr aes256-gcm@openssh.com chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com; do openssl rand 1000000000 2> /dev/null | ssh -c $i root@x.local "(time -p cat) > /dev/null" 2>&1 | grep real | awk '{print "'$i': "1000 / $2" MB/s" }'; done
3des-cbc: 153.61 MB/s
aes128-cbc: 153.139 MB/s
aes128-ctr: 152.439 MB/s
aes128-gcm@openssh.com: 153.846 MB/s
aes192-cbc: 153.61 MB/s
aes192-ctr: 153.374 MB/s
aes256-cbc: 153.139 MB/s
aes256-ctr: 153.374 MB/s
aes256-gcm@openssh.com: 153.139 MB/s
chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com: 152.672 MB/s
sneak@nostromo-2:~$
```

x.local is a 40 core xeon with aes-ni on Ubuntu 18.04 x64, and is still entirely pegging a single core and appears to be cpu-bound (and not multithreaded).  It's a 10G link from an iMac Pro (also with too many cores) to x.local so I'm really confused why two machines both with aes-ni and with 70 cores between them on 10 gigabits can't manage to encrypt/decrypt faster than that.

Using `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1000000 count=1000` instead of `openssl rand` yields the same results.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You might try testing your network speed with netcat since I'm not sure that `ssh` is the bottleneck. Log into `x.local` and run the command

```
nc -v -l 2222 > /dev/null
```

Then, from `nostromo`, run

```
 dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024K count=512 | nc -v x.local 2222
```

See if the transfer speed goes up. If not, then `ssh` is not the problem.

Comment: Ahh, good call.  It doesn't go faster, but now nc on both systems is pegging a single core.  I feel like pushing zeroes between FDs should be able to go more than 150MiB/sec, perhaps something else is wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you're actually running a 1Gb network (8 * 150MB/s = 1Gb/s). How sure are you about the two adapters and any switches in between?